# Typo3 - extbase - Missing type information, probably no @param annotation for parameter "$currentPage"

Tags: annotations, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I get the following error in Typo3 Backend:

```
Missing type information, probably no @param annotation for parameter "$currentPage" in Tx_OptivoBm_Controller_NewsletterController->newAction()
```

The function is set up like that:

```
/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param $currentPage
 * @param $newNewsletter
 * @dontvalidate $newNewsletter
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction($currentPage) {
    if (!isset($currentPage)){
        $this->redirect('index');
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param array $currentPage
 * @param $newNewsletter
 * @dontvalidate $newNewsletter
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction(array $currentPage) {
    if (!isset($currentPage)){
        $this->redirect('index');
    }
}
```

but that not make a difference.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

-- Thanks to @Fixus --

```
/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param array $currentPage
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction($currentPage) {
    if (!isset($currentPage)){
        $this->redirect('index');
    }
}
```

This is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare param you need to set type of it. For all of them not only one.
when you're not sure what type will be set use 'mixed'

why you have `@param $newNewsletter` if it is not declared in method ? Either delete this annotation or add it to the definition

don't make `array $currentPage` in method declaration. Simple type can provide some php errors

after all changes go to typo3temp and clear it manualy (not from BE). Errors like this can be stored there and not cleared properly from BE